# maven variables processed before inheritance

Tags: maven, scope

I was surprised to learn (both from experimentation and [from this documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Interpolation)) that in maven:

> variables are processed after inheritance as outlined above. This means that if a parent project uses a variable, then its definition in the child, not the parent, will be the one eventually used."

Is there a standard practice if you want the opposite behavior (for at least one variable)?

What I'm trying to do is have a multi-module project (ProjA) that refers to the other modules by ${project.version}.  I keep all of the versions in sync for this project.  The problem is that when another project (ProjB) uses ProjA as a parent, all of the references to ${project.version} in ProjA resolve to ProjB's version.  Definitely not what I want.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you do and what you like to do? May be put an example project on Github?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by „_a multi-module project (ProjA) that refers to the other modules by ${project.version}_“? Can you add sample POMs for _ProjA_ and _ProjB, ProjC_, limited to relevant content, to your question?

Comment: Please see my [sample github repository](https://github.com/ahousing/stackoverflow.32533963).  Specifically, it's the combo of [line 26 of projA/subX/pom.xml](https://github.com/ahousing/stackoverflow.32533963/blob/master/projA/subX/pom.xml) and [line 15 of projB/pom.xml](https://github.com/ahousing/stackoverflow.32533963/blob/master/projB/pom.xml) that's causing me grief.  I'm hoping for some syntax for [line 26](https://github.com/ahousing/stackoverflow.32533963/blob/master/projA/subX/pom.xml) that would mean "use the version for projA, and not any other definition of {project.version}".

Comment: I ended up hard-coding the version, and using version plugin to set the version (which also updated my dependency).  This seems like a hack to me, but works for what I'm doing.